# Complex PBI Dax Use Case

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

I have this complex use case, I need to get a list of projects or flag them in DAX based on the following:

-if a project has multiple expense types then flag :

```
The project that has 5% or more in variance in **more than one** expense type but variance in 
$ is within 85k for those expense types.

-if project has one expense type then flag it when variance is above 5% but variance in $ is 
 less than 85K.
```

in the table below the projects MNO and EFG will be flagged because they fall within that criteria, project ABC won't because one of it's variance that is above 5% is also above 85K

I used this to identify which projects have multiple expense type

*Column =
Var __MultiExpenseType= CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Projects Summary'[Expense Type]), ALLEXCEPT('Projects Summary','Projects Summary'[Project]))
RETURN
__MultiExpenseType > 1*

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

------------Update-------------
someone suggested the creation of 2 columns,

```
Var Criteria Threshold = 
 Var __result= 
 CALCULATE (SUMX(
                    VALUES('Projects Summary'[Project]),
                    VAR __varPERC = MAX('Projects Summary'[Var to Budget %])
                    VAR __varCurr = MIN('Projects Summary'[Var to Budget])
                    RETURN 
                    IF(__varPERC> 0.05 && __varCurr <83000,1,0)
 )
 )
RETURN 
__result
```

and then create another one

```
flag projects for Variance threshold = 
VAR __Criteria=
    SUMX( VALUES('Projects Summary'[Project]),
    VAR __Project = SELECTEDVALUE('Projects Summary'[Project])
    VAR __expenseType = SELECTEDVALUE('Projects Summary'[Expense Type])
    
    RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        MIN( 'Projects Summary'[Var Criteria Threshold]),
        ALL('Projects Summary'),
        'Projects Summary'[Project]= __Project  && 'Projects Summary'[Expense Type]=__expenseType
    )
)
RETURN
__Criteria
```

But when I create the second one I get an error of circular dependency between the 2 columns but I don't understand why!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Column = 
VAR vTable =
CALCULATETABLE (
    SUMMARIZE ( 'Projects Summary', 'Projects Summary'[Project], 'Projects Summary'[Expense Type] ),
    FILTER (
        'Projects Summary',
        CALCULATE (
            MAX ( 'Projects Summary'[Variance in $] ),
            ALLEXCEPT ( 'Projects Summary', 'Projects Summary'[Project] )
        ) < 85000
            && 'Projects Summary'[Variance in %] >= 0.05
    )
)
RETURN
    COUNTROWS(vTable) >= 1
```

Now just apply conditional formatting for the 'true' items.

Comment: Thank you so much Erick, how can I guarantee that it will only take a project if it has more than 5% in more than one expense type? because if it has above 5%  in just one expense type it shouldn't be flagged

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example with the MNO project, I considered not only those who had more than one expense. To consider only those that contain more than one expense, use the measure:

```
Column = 
VAR vTable =
CALCULATETABLE (
    SUMMARIZE ( 'Projects Summary', 'Projects Summary'[Project], 'Projects Summary'[Expense Type] ),
    FILTER (
        'Projects Summary',
        CALCULATE (
            MAX ( 'Projects Summary'[Variance in $] ),
            ALLEXCEPT ( 'Projects Summary', 'Projects Summary'[Project] )
        ) < 85000
            && 'Projects Summary'[Variance in %] >= 0.05
            && CALCULATE (
                DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Projects Summary'[Expense Type] ),
                ALLEXCEPT ( 'Projects Summary', 'Projects Summary'[Project] )
            ) > 1
    )
)
RETURN
    COUNTROWS(vTable) >= 1
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me, so the condition is that if a project has 2 or more expense type with variance above 5% and those expense types have variance in money less than 85K then it should be true.

Comment: That's right, Rachel.

Comment: for some reason this column gives me always true even when there are rows where it should be false (bigger than 85K) , I am trying to figure out what I need to change to make it work (sorry for the delay in marking it as the solution)